# Is it possible to run Django tests on Apache instead of the development server?

Tags: django, apache, testing, mod-wsgi, django-testing

When I test my Django web application with `python manage.py test`, this starts Django's development server and runs the test.

I want to run my Django tests on my production stack. Specifically, I want to use Apache instead of Django's development server. Is there a way to do this?

I've looked through the docs for [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase), but it doesn't seem to be customizable in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

The [`LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase) launches a Django server. You can then test it using a client like selenium.

In your case, you are already running the production server that you want to test, that means you don't require the Django server of `LiveServerTestCase`, or the fixture loading of `TestCase`. Just use [`SimpleTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase). You can then test the live server using a client like selenium.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase) demonstrate how to use selenium. In your case, you just need to set `self.live_server_url` to the domain that Apache is running on.